# keyboard repeats some keys during fast type

Tags: kernel, keyboard, hardware

When i type fast sometimes i get double input, like typing `the` got `thee`, typing `kernel` got `kerrnel`. Same behaviour in unity and tty, so there is no point in looking into X server settings. Of course, i tried to open and cleanup my keyboard. I use HP Sleekbook 4 laptop, ubuntu 16.10, and 4.9.0-040900rc8-generic kernel, but i checked stable kernel versions too, and got same problem. Forr now i'm trying to find some usable `kbdrate` parameters, but no luck for now. Any ideas? I found there was an alike problem with dell laptops and got fixed after they released bios update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something I found useful was a wireless USB keyboard. The transmitter is inside a USB female connector so it's much much faster than say bluetooth would be. If you're going to get a new keyboard go wireless, because your ability to move around while working will likely help you relax and increase your productivity over just pure speed. It worked for me esp towards online gaming. Frankly I think your only other alternative is to chill out and type slowerr...

Comment: But we are talking about laptop here, so getting wireless keyboard is not an option.